# Ошибка при парсинге json-данных

Tags: javascript, json

Нужно передать массив точек через json. На сайте используется шаблонизатор ejs. Есть блок:

```
<div class="map" data-points="<%- JSON.stringify({points: ['point1','point2','point3']}) %>"></div>
```

а также js-файл, в котором нужно принять эти data-данные:

```
const points = $.parseJSON($('.map').data('points'));
```

в результате консоль выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

подскажите, как правильно принять json-данные в js-файле?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте значение атрибута data-points, которое в итоге хранится в div. Похоже JSON.stringify выдает строку с кавычками и значение вашего атрибута - невалидная строка. Попробуйте записать атрибут через одинарные кавычнки, а его значение через двойные:

```
<div class="map" data-points='<%- JSON.stringify({points: ["point1","point2","point3"]}) %>'></div>
```